# How to solve Pymodbus exception when Master requests for holding registry values of the Arduino Slave

Tags: python, c++, arduino, modbus, pymodbus

I currently trying to receive data from my Arduino slave to my computer. I am successful in creating an Arduino slave. However, when I am trying to receive the data from my computer using the Pymodbus library, my code fails to receive the data from the Arduino and raises a ModbusIOException. For the specifications of my project, I am trying to build a Modbus RTU with the Arduino to simulate a sensor with random numbers as readings. The Arduino code uses the Modbus-Arduino library of Andre Sarmento.

https://github.com/andresarmento/modbus-arduino

I already checked my Arduino slave if it is working. I tried reading the data through a Modbus Master emulator (QModMaster), and it worked just fine. This might prove that the problem itself is from the code for the Master. Furthermore, the serial connection seems to work fine, since the self.client.connect() returns True.

These are the screenshots of the QModMaster configurations.

[Slave configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGFSu.png)
[Serial Port configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e50Mh.png)

Python code for the master:

```
class ModbusRTU:
    def __init__(self, graph_name, port, baudrate=9600, 
                 stopbits=1, bytesize=8, parity='N', 
                 timeout=1):                                       
        self.graph_name = graph_name
        self.client = ModbusSerialClient(method='rtu', 
                                         port=port, 
                                         baudrate=baudrate, 
                                         parity=parity, 
                                         timeout=timeout)
        self.connection = self.client.connect()
        result = self.client.read_holding_registers(address=0, 
                                                  count=2, 
                                                  unit=1)
        print(result.registers) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    modbus = ModbusRTU(graph_name='/dev/ttyACM0', 
                       port='/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=9600, 
                       stopbits=1, bytesize=8, parity='N', 
                       timeout=1)
    print(modbus.check_connection())
```

Arduino code for the simulated slave and sensor:

```
#include <Modbus.h>
#include <ModbusSerial.h>

ModbusSerial mb;
const int READING = 0;
const int DECIMAL = 1;

void setup() {
  mb.config(&Serial, 9600, SERIAL_8N1);
  mb.setSlaveId(1);
  mb.addHreg(READING);
  mb.addHreg(DECIMAL);
}

void loop() {
  mb.task();
  mb.Hreg(READING, random(1, 201));
  mb.Hreg(DECIMAL, random(0, 4));
}
```

Upon printing the `results.registers`, it is supposedly a list of integers. However, it just raises a ModbusIOException with a message of:

```
'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'
  File "/home/kebaranas/PythonProjects/ThirsyWell/tools/utilities.py", line 21, in __init__
    print(result.registers)
  File "/home/kebaranas/PythonProjects/ThirsyWell/tools/utilities.py", line 29, in <module>
    timeout=1)
```

It also gives this message as well.

```
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found out the solution for this thanks for the help of few people. The QModMaster uses a library called libmodbus. Since the Arduino simulated slave and sensor worked with QModMaster, it would be easier to change the previous library and instead use libmodbus. Luckily, there is a python equivalent for libmodbus which is pylibmodbus. This is the link for the library https://github.com/stephane/pylibmodbus.

```
    from pylibmodbus import ModbusRtu


    class ModbusRTU:
        def __init__(self, port, baudrate=9600, databit=8, parity='None', 
                     stopbit=1, timeout=1000):
            self.parity = {'Odd': 'O', 'Even': 'E', 'None': 'N'}
            self.modbus = ModbusRtu(device=port.encode('ascii'),   
                                    data_bit=databit, baud=baudrate,
                                    parity=self.parity[parity] \
                                           .encode('ascii'), 
                                    stop_bit=stopbit)
            self.modbus.set_response_timeout(timeout/1000)
            self.modbus.connect()
            self.modbus.set_slave(1)
            result = self.modbus.read_registers(0, 2)
            print(result)
            self.modbus.close()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main = ModbusRTU('/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=9600, databit=8, 
                         parity='None', stopbit=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Before `print(result.registers)` try the following code snippet:

```
if not result.isError():
    print(result.registers)
else:
    print("error: {}".format(result))
```

Also, fill in other `ModbusSerialClient()` argument.

Here is updated of your code snippet:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient

class ModbusRTU:
    def __init__(self, graph_name, port, baudrate=9600,
                 stopbits=1, bytesize=8, parity='N',
                 timeout=1):
        self.graph_name = graph_name
        self.client = ModbusSerialClient(
            method='rtu',
            port=port,
            baudrate=baudrate,
            parity=parity,
            timeout=timeout,
            stopbits=stopbits,
            bytesize=bytesize
        )
        self.connection = self.client.connect()
        result = self.client.read_input_registers(address=1,
                                                  count=2,
                                                  unit=1)
        if not result.isError():
            print(result.registers)
        else:
            print("error: {}".format(result))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    modbus = ModbusRTU(
        graph_name='/dev/ttyACM0',
        port='/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=9600,
        stopbits=1, bytesize=8, parity='N',
        timeout=1
    )
```

Comment: The console gave this message: error: Exception Response(129, 1, IllegalAddress)

Comment: do you have certain about `address=1`?

Comment: As far as I know, the address is determined by the first holding register which can be determined by const int READING = 1; and mb.addHreg(READING); from the Arduino code. Based on what I read, the Pymodbus method automatically adds 40000 which is the actual address of the holding register. Meanwhile, the unit id is the same as slave id, which is determined by mb.setSlaveId(1);. When the address and id are matching, the console gives this error message: Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)

Answer (score 1):

You're defining holding registers in your slave but you're trying to read them as input registers, try changing this line:

```
result = self.client.read_input_registers(address=1, count=2, unit=1)
```

To:

```
result = self.client.read_holding_registers(address=1, count=2, unit=1)
```

Be aware that the Modbus spec defines this two different types of registers: holding and input, depending on the memory region they are placed in.

Comment: Pardon my mistake to change the method again. However I already tried to use the read_holding_register method, and the console just wrote this message again: Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)

Comment: No problem. The error you see means you're not getting any data back. The only other thing I can think of is the timeout setting but you already have it quite high at 1 second. Maybe there is a way to define it for the Arduino too? Are you doind the connection directly on TTL? or you're going though RS485? What hardware you have on the computer side?

Comment: I haven't thought of defining the timeout in the Arduino side. As of now I am just doing the connection through the USB jack of the Arduino.

Comment: OK. I see no reason for you to be able to connect with QModMaster and not with Pymodbus. Maybe you can give it a go to pylibmodbus instead https://github.com/stephane/pylibmodbus Otherwise, maybe you can post a screenshot with the settings you have in QModMaster

Comment: I updated the post with the screenshots of the QModMaster settings. I am currently trying to use pylibmodbus instead.

Comment: I see... Are you using Windows for QModMaster but Linux for pymodbus? Are you sure you're using the same port? maybe run "dmesg | grep tty" right after you attach the USB connector and see what the kernel reports?

Comment: Yup, I am using Windows for QModMaster and Linus for pymodbus. It wrote this message: [    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    1.459900] tty ptmx: hash matches
[ 2573.361290] cdc_acm 3-3:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[10973.937479] cdc_acm 1-1.2:1.1: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[10981.955749] cdc_acm 1-1.2:1.1: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[11009.840820] cdc_acm 1-1.2:1.1: ttyACM1: USB ACM device

Comment: So you do actually have two ports, /dev/ttyACM0 and /dev/ttyACM1. I'm a bit confused about that. Have you tried pymodbus with both?

Comment: As far as I can tell both can pertain to the Arduino Mega. However right now the Arduino software only identifies the Mega as /dev/ttyACM0 and not /dev/ttyACM1. I tried both, Pymodbus was able to connect with /dev/ttyACM0  (returns True) while /dev/ttyACM1 did not. I am confused as well why /dev/ttyACM1 should be there as well since I only have 1 Mega connected to my PC.

Comment: Correction! /dev/ttyACM1 is actually my phone connected to my PC which I just recently connected. Somehow when I try to re execute the command the port name remains even I removed it from the PC.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. Sometimes you have devices with more than one serial port though. I guess you're completely sure the code on your Arduino is running, correct? Are you still getting IllegalAddress? or again no registers (ModbusIOException)?

Comment: After applying Benyamin Jafari's solution, I get a more specific error message like this: Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received). Nonetheless, it is the same old ModbusIOException when I don't apply his solution.

Comment: That's the error you normally get when you have problems with your  hardware but that not your case if you're not having the same issue on Windows... There must be something we are missing. I'll try to reproduce your  setup as soon as I can

Comment: I have tested several different configurations (on my Teensy 3.6, I don't have any Arduinos) and I can confirm your Python code is not the problem. I cannot compile the Modbus library you're using on your Arduino with the USB serial port (&Serial), it only works for hardware serial ports (non-USB like &Serial1). I guess that's related to my hardware. On USB I got this one working: https://github.com/stephane/modbusino maybe you can give it a go, but be aware that is quite limited...

Comment: What really eludes me is how you made it work with QModMaster and not with Python, that's something I could not reproduce. All configurations I got to work were behaving the same with any Modbus client.

Comment: I tried Modbusino as well before. I did not work for both QModMaster and for my Python code.

Comment: I see... I guess it's just a hardware issue. I don't think I can help you further without testing in the exact same platform but I'll keep an eye in case you find a solution. Good luck!

Comment: Something else occurred to me: have you tested your Arduino serial port on Linux? Maybe you can grab a simple sketch that prints numbers to the console to make sure everything is working: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print but be sure to test it under Linux (you can use stty or minicom)

Comment: I used pylibmodbus, and it worked. Thanks! I will update my own question about this later.

Comment: great. I never experienced different behavior using libmodbus or pymodbus, certainly not something like this.